# How to prove that $\phi (x,\frac{1}{x}) = x$ and $ \psi( x) = (x,\frac{1}{x}) $ are morphisms of varieties?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-varieties

Hartshorne say that a $ \phi : V \to W$ is a morphism of variety if it is continuous and for every regular function $f$ on $W$, the map $ f \circ \phi^{-1} $ is also regular function.

Using this definition, how do we show that $\phi : Z(XY-1) \to \mathbb{A}^1 -\{0\}$ s.t.$ (x,\frac{1}{x}) \mapsto x$ and the inverse map $ \psi :  \mathbb{A}^1 -\{0\}  \to Z(XY-1)$ s.t. $  x \mapsto (x,\frac{1}{x}) $ are both morphisms of varieties.

Comment: A regular function on an open subset of a variety is a function which can be locally expressed as a rational function (so for $Z(XY-1)$, quotients of polynomials in $X$ and $Y$, and for ${\bf A}^1$, quotients of polynomials in $x$). Now $\phi$ and $\psi$ clearly send such functions to other functions of the same type.